# Text from sysListView32 tree

Tags: c++, winapi

Itrying to get a out of a string sysListView32 from another process.
The list is a tree. And for the first column returns an empty string.
Tell me where is the problem?

Image of tree:
[tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86qCb.png)
Code:

```
vProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_READ |
    PROCESS_VM_WRITE, False, vProcessId);
 vPointer = VirtualAllocEx(vProcess, NULL, 4096, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT,
    PAGE_READWRITE);
 vItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
 vItem.iItem = I;
 vItem.iSubItem = J;
 vItem.cchTextMax = sizeof(vBuffer);
 vItem.pszText = (wchar_t*)vPointer +sizeof(TLVItem);
 WriteProcessMemory(vProcess, vPointer, &vItem, sizeof(TLVItem),
            &vNumberOfBytesRead);
 SendMessageW(mHandle, LVM_GETITEMW, I, (LPARAM)vPointer);
 ReadProcessMemory(vProcess, (wchar_t*)vPointer +sizeof(TLVItem),
            vBuffer, sizeof(vBuffer), &vNumberOfBytesRead);
 RESULT = UnicodeString(vBuffer);

 VirtualFreeEx(vProcess, vPointer, 0, MEM_RELEASE); // free mem
 CloseHandle(vProcess);
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't VirtualAlloc the memory block in the target process, so it isn't there.

Instead of using extreme hackery to try to get this, why not use one of the accessibility APIs to get this info cross-process. UIA, for example, goes down to XP and supports this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms726294(VS.85).aspx

Martyn

Comment: Is it not the memory allocation in another process?
vProcess = OpenProcess (PROCESS_VM_OPERATION....
vPointer = VirtualAllocEx (vProcess, ....

Comment: You are right, I missed that. But then you are sending vPointer to SendMessage when vPointer isn't a valid address in the source process. 

I renew my belief that you should use UIA.

Comment: I ran a utility named UISpy.ehe, and it is unable to obtain a text of the first column, just like my code. The second column normally reads my code...Empty strings...  http://i.piccy.info/i5/26/21/1742126/Snymok5.png