# Control Google Chrome from .Net application

Tags: .net, google-chrome, webbrowser-control

I need a way to control Google Chrome from .net code (such as the Web Browser for IE).
In my code I have to access Chrome Application so the standards solution did not work.
I already tried the Awesomium and webkit .net.

If there is an alternative way in any developing language I'm willing to try it as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Awesomium is working ok (with some quirks), if that's what you're asking - from C#

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Selenium .Net - it's meant to help with unit testing web applications, but you can use it to arbitrarily control different browsers from within .Net.

Answer (score 0):

You might try Automation UI, for instance, you can use Inspect.exe to get every handle of almost every window and child controls, such as buttons, see the highlighted rectangle.

[image]

Given these UI [AutomationElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.aspx) handles, you can do almost everything you can do interactively.

Comment: last time I tried this some things were working, some not - are you able to pick a text, links etc.

Comment: I would say at least 90% works, other than some really advanced requirement, such as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15808546/get-win32-legacy-controls-tooltip-text-programmatically, I have offered 150 bounties, but still no satisfactory reply.

Comment: I may take a look at it if bounty is still on :) I did play with it as well - I needed more around '**text**' stuff and that wasn't great, working, but